# CakePHP - One HABTM With Two Foreign Keys

Tags: php, cakephp, model, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've been trying to save two foreign keys to the same row of a join table with no success.  My `Client` model has two HABTM association with both `User` and `Group` models, a user can have many clients and create clients under many different groups.

The UserClient join table looks like this:

```
+----+---------+----------+-----------+
| id | user_id | group_id | client_id |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+
|  1 |       1 |        1 |         1 |
|  2 |       1 |        2 |         2 |
|  3 |       3 |        4 |         3 |
+----+---------+---------+------------+
```

Client model:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'UserClient',
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id'
    ),
    'Group' => array(
        'className' => 'Group',
        'joinTable' => 'UserClient',
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'group_id'
    )
);
```

Client view:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Client'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Client'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('phone');

        echo $this->Form->input('Client', array('multiple'=> 'false', 'options' => $group_ids));
        echo $this->Form->hidden('User', array('value' => $user_id));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

This works to a point, however instead of saving `user_id`, `group_id` and `client_id` to the same row in UserClient table, it create two separate rows for each HABTM, `user_id`, `client_id` get saved to one row and `group_id`, `client_id` get saved to another.

Is there any way to define multiple `associationForeignKey` within the same HABTM association so `user_id`, `group_id` and `client_id` get saved to the same row when creating a new client?

Answer (score 1):

When you have to store additional fields in a `HABTM` relation, it is sometimes easier to use a join model. In your case this would mean creating a model for your `UserClient` table and use `hasMany` relations instead of `HABTM`.

Then of course you'll have to manage the save manually, but you'll have much more control of what must be done. You can find a few words about this in the [Cake documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model).